# CodeIgniter : core/ override, missing load/loader class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, i am having this issue and google is not helping and i think it is because my issue is too simple or something.

I'm trying to `load` whatever or connect with `load->database();` but it aint working.

Here is my code with comments, it will explain everything.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CI_Lang {

    function __construct() {
        # Show all files included
        print_r(get_included_files()); // There is nothing like loader or load .php

        # Check for loader file
        if( ! class_exists('loader') || ! class_exists('load')) {
            echo 'no load '; // is being shown,
        }

        # Check Database connection before
        if (isset($this->db->conn_id) && is_resource($this->db->conn_id)) {
            echo 'database is loaded and conected ';
        } else {
            echo 'no connection '; // is being shown,
        }

        # Get Database connection
        $this->load->library('database');
        /*
            Script dies on line above with error:
            Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in 
            application/core/Lang.php on line 38
        */

        $this->load->database();

        # Check Database connection after
        if (isset($this->db->conn_id) && is_resource($this->db->conn_id)) {
            echo 'database is loaded and conected ';
        } else {
            echo 'no connection ';
        }



        # Register as loaded
        log_message('debug', 'JK_Lang Class initialized');
    }
}
```

This script is named `Lang.php` and it is in `application/core` folder. It is supposed to override the main Lang class and it is. The problem is, it seems to be all alone. How can i include other methods here?

I already have modified `autoload.php` and set there:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    # We need Loader
    'loader',
    # Connect with DB
    'database',

    # Session Start
    'session'
);
```

And now i have ran out of ideas, any help please ?

Comment: Why am i getting downgrades/downvotes, is there something wrong with my question that i should know? Please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, i had no codeigniter instance declared. So there were 2 methods to fix it.

First, i could make a function like:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->run();
}

function run() {
    /* All my __construct code here */
}
```

Or as i actually fixed my problem, i made a library and to get all things needed to work with codeigniter i made an instance:

```
class L {
    var $CI;

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();

        $this->test();
    }

    function test() {
        $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow.com`");
    }
}
```